# How do you ask someone to '' please yobisute ''?

Tags: grammar, politeness, formality

I just learned about the concept of yobisute.

If someone calls me John San , and I want them to drop the honorific and just call me John how should I say this ?

Would it be just ''Yobisute kudasai'' or maybe ''Yobisute onegaishimase'' or some other variant.

What is the usual way of expressing this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly:

> 呼び捨ててください。
>
> 呼び捨てでいい（です）。
>
> 呼び捨てで構いません。

Note: in the first case 呼び捨てて is a verb in the latter 呼び捨て is a noun.

Otherwise it sounds a bit more natural without using the phrase 呼び捨て itself, so depending on context and your level of closeness with the other person:

> ジョンと呼んでください。さんは不要です。
>
> さんをつけることありませんよ、ジョンと呼んでください。
>
> さんは使わなくてもいい（です）。
>
> さんをつけなくてもいい（です）。
>
> さんではなく、ジョンで結構です。
>
> 名前だけで呼んでください。
>
> ジョンだけで結構です。
>
> さんなしで嬉しいです。
>
> ジョンで大丈夫（です）。
>
> ジョンでいいよ。

Probably there is no limit to the ways you can ask this.

You can also go the other way (beware of some irony here):

> 〇〇様にさんという敬称を使わないでいただければ幸いでございます。

Comment: Wouldn't John be ジョン

Comment: Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: `使わなくていただければ` ← ✖「V+なくていただく」 ◎「V+ないでいただく」

Comment: @Chocolate Thank you for correcting.